# Flutter using StreamingSharedPreferences in MultiProvider

Tags: flutter

this is simple of implementation for `StreamingSharedPreferences` using `Provider`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final preferences = await StreamingSharedPreferences.instance;
  final settings = MyAppSettings(preferences);

  runApp(
    Provider<MyAppSettings>.value(value: settings, child: MyApp()),
  );
}
```

as i have another multiple `Provider` in application such as:

```
runApp(
  MultiProvider(providers: [
    Provider(builder: (_) => database.userTableDao),
    Provider(builder: (_) => database.postsTableDao),
    Provider(builder: (_) => database.postsTableDao),
    Provider(
      builder: (_) => ApiService.create(),
      dispose: (_, ApiService) => service.client.dispose(),
    )
  ], child: OKToast(child: MyHomePage())),
);
```

i'm not sure how can make `StreamingSharedPreferences` provider inside them, for example:

```
MultiProvider(providers: [
  ...
  Provider<ApplicationSettings>.value(value: settings),
  ...
], child: OKToast(child: MyHomePage())),
```

Comment: Sorry, but re-using an old question to bypass bounty-posting time limits is not something we can accept.

Comment: No wonder, I was wondering why such a question from a year ago didn't get any answers

Answer (score 0):

in this code i used instance of `StreamingSharedPreferences.instance` into `main` function and after that i added inside `MultiProvider`, for example:

```
final settings = ApplicationSettings( await StreamingSharedPreferences.instance );

MultiProvider(providers: [
  ...
  Provider( builder: (_) => settings ),
  ...
], child: OKToast(child: MyHomePage())),
```

Comment: @DenisV i explanationed